# Is it possible to apply a search function when using Get and Set?

Tags: java, forms, search, setter, getter

Sorry, I'm new to Java and there's probably a very simple answer to this.

At the moment, I'm printing all the results out in individual `JOptionPane`s.
I would like to set up a **search function** to allow me to show certain results based on a given criteria.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create new Person objects
        Address p1 = new Address("27","Abbey View","Hexham","NE46 1EQ");
        Address p2 = new Address("15", "Chirdon Crescent", "Hexham", "NE46 1LE");
        Address p3 = new Address("6", "Causey Brae", "Hexham", "NE46 1DB");

        Details c1 = new Details();
        Details c2 = new Details();
        Details c3 = new Details();

        //Send some messages to the  objects
        c1.setBeds("3 ");
        c2.setBeds("6");
        c3.setBeds("4");

        c1.setPrice("175,000");
        c2.setPrice("300,00");
        c3.setPrice("250,000");

        c1.setType("Terraced");
        c2.setType("Bungalow");
        c3.setType("Detached");

        //Set up the association
        p1.ownsDetails(c1);
        p2.ownsDetails(c2);
        p3.ownsDetails(c3);

        //Print result
        p1.printDetails();
        p2.printDetails();
        p3.printDetails();

        //Finally quit
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having three separate variables, you may find it helpful to have an array:

```
Address p[] = new Address[3];
p[0] = new Address("27","Abbey View","Hexham","NE46 1EQ");
p[1] = new Address("15", "Chirdon Crescent", "Hexham", "NE46 1LE");
p[2] = new Address("6", "Causey Brae", "Hexham", "NE46 1DB");
```

Now it's possible to write a loop to examine each one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (p[i].getSomething().equals(thingToSearch)) {
        // ... it's a match!
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a custom `JDialog` or `JFrame` that has multiple input fields and multiple results that appear due to searching.

Ideally, your objects would need to be **in a list or array** to do the searching,
so that you can loop over all of them and find matches.